# ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE returns imagefile as Extra instead of Data

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-5.0-lollipop, huawei-mobile-services

One feature of my app includes the camera. The user takes a picture and the app displays the image.

I start an intent with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE using StartActivityForResult and capture the response with onActivityResult. **Usually** I can simply call *getData()* on the intent I receive in onActivityResult and get the content uri for the MediaProvider.

My problem is the following: One one of my test devices, a Huawei ALE-L21, the intent I get in onActivityResult has no data, but instead, it has a parcellable extra. How could I get the users photo from that? Android Studio doesn't tell me the name of the parcellable extra either

---

**Disclaimer: I call getActivity() because I'm using this code in a fragment**

---

This is what I use to get the camera.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.RQ_PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
}
```

---

And here's the code in my onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: //RQ_ImageCapture
        case 2: //RQ_ImageSelected
            if (resultIntent != null) {
                try {
                    Uri selectedImage = resultIntent.getData();
                    if(selectedImage != null) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = 
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                        setImageAsBackground(selectedImage, bitmap);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Usually I can simply call getData() on the intent I receive in onActivityResult and get the content uri for the MediaProvider.

Your code will fail on many of them, including all recent Nexus devices. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not supposed to return a `Uri`. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

> If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is useful for applications that only need a small image. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.

Since you are not including `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, you will get a `data` extra (`getData().getExtra("data")`) with a thumbnail image.

> the intent I get in onActivityResult has no data, but instead, it has a parcellable extra

Given your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request, that is what you are supposed to get.

If you want a full-size image, include `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, perhaps pointing to a `FileProvider` in your app, such as I demonstrate in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider). Then, you know the `Uri` where the photo should go, because you specified that `Uri`.

Comment: god bless you buddy